# SQL Query optimizing without WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I have a simple MYSQL table with 10M rows. It needs optimization but I'm not sure why this simple select takes so long. It seems like the query time, before streaming results.

Any good links on setup performance tuning? Very dated ex: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/29/what-to-tune-in-mysql-server-after-installation/

```
##QUERY: 
SELECT * FROM scga_results;

mysql-slow.log
# Time: 120126 15:05:03
# User@Host: abc[abc] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 25  Lock_time: 0  Rows_sent: 11896464  Rows_examined: 11896464
select * from scga_results;

##REF
mysql> describe scga_results;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| application  | varchar(255)     | NO   | MUL |                   |                |
| field        | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| value        | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| period       | varchar(255)     | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| end_time     | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| date_updated | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show table status like 'scga_results'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: scga_results
         Engine: MyISAM
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Dynamic
           Rows: 11897025
 Avg_row_length: 96
    Data_length: 1152314616
Max_data_length: 281474976710655
   Index_length: 180028416
      Data_free: 0
 Auto_increment: 11971193
    Create_time: 2012-01-26 13:32:57
    Update_time: 2012-01-27 00:20:04
     Check_time: 2012-01-26 13:39:19
      Collation: latin1_swedish_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options:
        Comment:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Adding query details**

```
USES KEY:
mysql> explain select * from scga_results where application="20000";
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | scga_results | ref  | index_2       | index_2 | 257     | const |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.26 sec)

NO KEY USED: 
mysql> explain select * from scga_results where id="20";
mysql> explain select * from scga_results where period="day";
mysql> explain select * from scga_results where application>0;
```

**Adding profile detail**

```
mysql> SET PROFILING=1;
mysql> SELECT * FROM scga_results;

------------------+---------------------+
11897787 rows in set (23.05 sec)

mysql> show profiles;
+----------+-------------+-----------------------------+
| Query_ID | Duration    | Query                       |
+----------+-------------+-----------------------------+
|        1 |  6.72981800 | select id from scga_results |
|        2 | 23.06871000 | select * from scga_results  |
+----------+-------------+-----------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 2;
+--------------------------------+-----------+
| Status                         | Duration  |
+--------------------------------+-----------+
| (initialization)               | 0.000008  |
| checking query cache for query | 0.000047  |
| checking permissions           | 0.00001   |
| Opening tables                 | 0.000013  |
| System lock                    | 0.000007  |
| Table lock                     | 0.000026  |
| init                           | 0.000023  |
| optimizing                     | 0.000006  |
| statistics                     | 0.000015  |
| preparing                      | 0.000013  |
| executing                      | 0.000004  |
| Sending data                   | 23.055196 |
| end                            | 0.000018  |
| query end                      | 0.000007  |
| freeing items                  | 0.000014  |
| closing tables                 | 0.000009  |
| logging slow query             | 0.013294  |
+--------------------------------+-----------+
17 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Without a `WHERE` clause, you're forcing the database to traverse the entire dataset (10M rows). If you have a slow disk, that could take 25s.

Comment: this is not a simple select but rather a worst one. It does a full table scan reading all pages from disk. If you dont provide conditions with indexed fields you will get bad query times. The table stat has to be gathered and indexes rebuilt and so on....

Comment: The column `application` is varchar you run `WHERE application>0` ?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are retrieving more then 1GB of data.  If you really need all of that data faster, I think you are going to need hardware changes.

Your query may be running slower than you want due to other loads on the server, but more than likely you are reaching the limit of what your hardware can deliver.

You could try switching to a faster hard drive, certain types of RAID hard drives, or some sort of solid state memory - even converting the table to a MEMORY table so it is held in RAM.  Keep in mind that this still will not make it instantaneous as the data has to go across the memory bus, etc.

Comment: This must be a design flaw in MySQL or a tuning problem. The simple `SELECT * FROM table` takes 30 seconds to run, before streaming results back. There shouldn't be any table scan or interpretation? Would changing --min-examined-row-limit  force MySQL to send results/ skip the table scan?

Comment: @Nick: If you want all rows, then all rows have to be read from the table (which is in disk usually). That is a table scan.

Comment: @ypercube I can't believe MySQL reads ALL results before sending any? I've now run a [tuning script](http://www.day32.com/MySQL/) and read some of this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-use.html. Performance: while reading $top shows cpu at %65, memory 0.3%. While sending cpu 7%, memory 58%. My tables will grown larger...

Comment: @Nick; I don't understand your comment. If you run `SELECT * FROM table`, then you want all rows. How will MySQL send them to you without reading the table?

Comment: Ah, if you mean that it can start sending as soon as it has read a few rows, yes, sure it does that.

Comment: @ypercube Yes - I want it to start sending rows as soon as the query runs. Since there is no `WHERE` filter this should happen immediatly but instead, MySQL is taking 30 seconds to read the whole table. There's no filtering so MySQL should start streaming off the top?

Comment: @Nick: Can you [profile](http://petewarden.typepad.com/searchbrowser/2008/10/how-to-profile-mysql.html) the query?

Comment: The `min-examined-row-limit` setting has nothing to do with how a query is run. It has to do with slow-logging, and if some queries will be logged in the slow-log or not.

Comment: @ypercube I added the profile information above. I think the profile detail is missing information as 23 seconds is the "scan" time, not "Sending data" time. As in it takes 23 seconds before MySQL starts sending date. At my console it takes 15 minutes to show the data stream. I'd like to eliminate the scan time. This server has 4GB ram. Thanks

Comment: Maybe others can make sense of this: Using the same MySQL account and query from a remote box, the query runs faster (~1sec) and never goes above 10% CPU/MEM.

Comment: @Nick: Not sure about this. It may have to do with buffers (and other) settings. Perhaps this question should be transfered to [http://dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com)